# Load GRIB variables with "unknown" typeOfLevel using cfgrib

Tags: python, grib, cfgrib

I'm trying to load GRIB2 files from DWD's ICON model using `xarray` and `cfgrib`. Most variables work fine, but for some (like for example `CLCL`), `xarray.open_dataset` raises the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/shared/conda/envs/devtools/lib/python3.8/site-packages/xarray/core/dataset.py", line 1398, in _construct_dataarray
    variable = self._variables[name]
KeyError: 'CLCL'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "DAT-2634/grib_file_loaders.py", line 276, in <module>
    df_cfgrib_sf = read_cfgrib_sf(grib_fns, nodes, params)
  File "DAT-2634/grib_file_loaders.py", line 115, in read_cfgrib_sf
    x = xr.open_dataset(
  File "/shared/conda/envs/devtools/lib/python3.8/site-packages/xarray/core/dataset.py", line 1502, in __getitem__
    return self._construct_dataarray(key)
  File "/shared/conda/envs/devtools/lib/python3.8/site-packages/xarray/core/dataset.py", line 1400, in _construct_dataarray
    _, name, variable = _get_virtual_variable(
  File "/shared/conda/envs/devtools/lib/python3.8/site-packages/xarray/core/dataset.py", line 173, in _get_virtual_variable
    ref_var = variables[ref_name]
KeyError: 'CLCL'
```

when I inspect the file via `grib_ls` I get

```
$ grib_ls ICON_europe_reg_0.125x0.125_2021101900_f000.grib2 | grep CLCL
2            edzw         20211019     fc           regular_ll   0            unknown      800          CLCL         grid_simple
```

I've read in the `cfgrib` issues [#195](https://github.com/ecmwf/cfgrib/issues/213) and [#213](https://github.com/ecmwf/cfgrib/issues/195) that this is probably due to the use of local codes and that I might be able to fix the issue using the appropriate code tables. DWD does provide [GRIB tables for ecCodes](https://opendata.dwd.de/weather/lib/grib/eccodes_definitions.edzw-2.19.0-2.tar.gz), but I'm not sure how to use them in combination with `cfgrib`.

**How can I use the custom code tables with `cfgrib`? Or is there another way to load these variables?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After not getting any further I've posted the same question [as an issue in the `cfgrib` GitHub project](https://github.com/ecmwf/cfgrib/issues/266), and got [a response](https://github.com/ecmwf/cfgrib/issues/266#issuecomment-973062416) there: the solution is to add the path of the custom code tables to the `ECCODES_DEFINITION_PATH` environment variable:

```py
import os
from pathlib import Path
import xarray

ECCODES_DEFINITION_PATHS = [
    # The custom codes I want to use
    Path('path/to/the/custom/codes'),

    # The codes from my system's ecCodes installation
    Path('/usr/share/eccodes/definitions'),
]
os.environ['ECCODES_DEFINITION_PATH'] = ':'.join(
    str(p.resolve())
    for p in ECCODES_DEFINITION_PATHS
)

x = xarray.open_dataset(...)
```

There is detailed documentation available [in the ECMWF wiki](https://confluence.ecmwf.int/display/UDOC/Creating+your+own+local+definitions+-+ecCodes+GRIB+FAQ).